# Etherscan like contract explorer for network deployed on localhost

Tags: contract-development, myetherwallet

Is there any EtherScan like explorer that I can run on my machine? I am running a network using Ganache, but it won't let me view the abi/details of my deployed contracts. I tried downloading MyEtherWallet and running it on my machine but that too won't let me see my deployed contracts.

Is there any alternative that I can use for development purpose to view my deployed contracts?

Comment: Looking for the same. polkadot-js website can point to a localhost chain, so I thought eth would have something similar?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are already using Ganache CLI, I'd recommend using the [Ganache GUI](https://www.trufflesuite.com/ganache), in order to achieve your desired outcome.

Comment: I am using Ganache GUI. It doesn't show me the contract details. It is telling me to add a truffle project to view the contracts. But I am not using truffle. I just want to view the contracts on my local deployed chain

Comment: @hkjhadj1 Is there a reason you aren't using Truffle? It works well and is fairly straightforward: https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/running-migrations

Comment: I've cloned an open source repo. They are not using truffle. Is there any way I can explore the contracts without it?